# Firing server side validations on moving from one page to another in Asp.NEt

Tags: asp.net

I need to fire certain server side validation for a page when the user is trying move from that page to another..

Even though he is not clicking on any buttons these server side validations have to be fired when he is moving out of this page..

Could you please help me how to handle this.. Required field validations will not happen as the user is entering the page and leaving the page without doing any action in the page..

Answer (score 0):

So you mean he's just changing the URL in the address bar? Or is he clicking something? If it's via clicking anything; you can just make whatever that thing is part of the appropriate validation group, and it will validate.

If he's just changing the URL, then you're going to need to detect leaving of the page (in JavaScript), and do some work. But depending on your scenario, I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: We are not sure what the user will click.. he can click on any tab or link and move away from this page.. But i need to fire the validation before he is leaving the page.

Comment: Search around for how to check for a user leaving/closing a page in JavaScript. You should find it easily.